# Regex: Capturing multiple instances in one word group

Tags: php, regex

I'm not good at Regex and I've been trying for hours now so I hope you can help me. I have this text:

```
&#x271D;his is *&#x271D;he* *in&#x271D;erne&#x271D;*
```

I need to capture (using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) only the `&#x271D;` in a word surrounded with `*`, so I only need to capture the last three `&#x271D;` in this example. The output array should look something like this:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 17
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 32
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 44
        )
```

I've tried using `(&#x271D;)` but ofcourse this will select all instances including the words without asterisks. Then I've tried `\*[^ ]*(&#x271D;)[^ ]*\*`  but this only gives me the last instance in one word. I've tried many other variations but all were wrong.

To clarify: The asterisk can be at all places in the string, but always at the beginning and end of a word. The opening asterisk always precedes a space except at the beginning of the string and the closing asterisk always ends with a space except at the end of the string. I must add that **punctuation marks can be inside these asterisks**. **`&#x271D;` is exactly (and only) what I need** to capture and can be at any position in a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches between the `*`. The anchor matches either at the start of the string, or at the end of the previous match.

```
(?:\*|\G(?!^))[^&*]*(?>&(?!#)[^&*]*)*\K&#x271D;(?=[^*]*\*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\*` Match `*`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[^&*]*` Match 0+ times any char except `&` and `*`
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `&(?!#)` Match `&` only when not directly followed by `#`
  - `[^&*]*` Match 0+ times any char except `&` and `*`
- `)*` Close atomic group and repeat 0+ times
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `&#x271D;` Match literally
- `(?=[^*]*\*)` Positive lookahead, assert a `*` at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8mrmLt/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kUrFv)

*For example*

```
$re = '/(?:\*|\G(?!^))[^&*]*(?>&(?!#)[^&*]*)*\K&#x271D;(?=[^*]*\*)/m';
$str = '&#x271D;his is *&#x271D;he* *in&#x271D;erne&#x271D;*';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => &#x271D;
            [1] => 43
        )

)
```

**Note** The the offset is 1 less than the expected as the string starts counting at 0. See [PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-parameters)

---

If you want to match more variations, you could use a non capturing group and list the ones that you would accept to match. If you don't want to cross newline boundaries you can exclude matching those in the negated character class.

```
(?:\*|\G(?!^))[^&*\r\n]*(?>&(?!#)[^&*\\rn]*)*\K&#(?:x271D|169);(?=[^*\r\n]*\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DagEYs/1)